# move symfony from root directory to public_html

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony2 project that somehow was running fine while it was outside the public_html directory, but now it's not working (the path is not allowed anymore, apparently).

Now I need to move the symfony2 directory into public_html, but when I do, the website is still not working (the page is blank).

I modified app.php so the include path is the correct one, and I also modified the projectConfiguration class so it has the right WebDir. What am I missing?

alternatively, how can I make it work outside the public_html directory?

for the record, I'm completely new to symfony.

Comment: Did you clear the symfony cache? You can always have the symfony project outside the public_html and have a virtual host pointing at the web folder in the symfony project.

Comment: Thanks fos.alex! The cache was the culprit! I manually cleaned it (I don't have access to the console) and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Newbie here. Is it fine to put all symfony code outside of public_html and keep whatever is in /web code in the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache was the culprit.
I cleaned symfony's cache (removed all the contents residing in the cache folder) and the website came back to normal.

thanks to fos.alex for the comment/answer.